# What`s the function of _Unchecked and _Rechecked?

Tags: c++, iterator, std, stl-algorithm

When I read the source code from `<algorithm>`, I see both. What's the function of `_Unchecked` and `_Rechecked`?

```
// TEMPLATE FUNCTION _Unchecked
template<class _Iter> inline
_Iter _Unchecked(_Iter _Src)
{    // construct unchecked from checked, generic
    return (_Src);
}

// TEMPLATE FUNCTION _Rechecked
template<class _Iter, class _UIter> inline
_Iter& _Rechecked(_Iter& _Dest, _UIter _Src)
{    // reset checked from unchecked, generic
    _Dest = _Src;
    return (_Dest);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an implementation detail of your compiler. But by the language I would assume this is Visual Studio. They tend to use the terms (un)checked to mean the following

[Checked Iterators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965.aspx)

> Checked iterators ensure that the bounds of your container are not overwritten.

You can see an example of this concept with their [`checked_array_iterator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985928.aspx) and [`unchecked_array_iterator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217887.aspx) classes.